# Diffeomorphism between open sets of half-space

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{H}^{m}=\left\{(x_{1},...,x_{m})|x_{m}\geq0\right\}$.
How can i prove that if $A$ and $B$ are respectively open set of $\mathbb{H}^{m}$ and of $\mathbb{H}^{n}$, with $n\ne m$, then they are not diffeomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

If they are diffeomorphisms then there is an isomorphism of their tangent spaces, which is a contradiction because the tangent spaces should have the same dimension.

Comment: Ok but this fact i have to prove is used to define the dimension of a manifold with boundary in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$...it is possible to prove it without using tangent space?